# How to read file that contains one row with multiple records- C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I have this text file that only has one row. Each file contains one customer name but multiple items and descriptions.
Record starting with 00 (Company Name) has a char length of 10
01 (Item#) - char length of 10
02 (Description) - char length of 50

I know how to read a file, but I don't have any idea of how to loop through only one line, find records 00, 01, 02 and grab the text based on the length, finally start at the position of the last records and start the loop again. Can someone please give me an idea of how to read files like this?

output:

```
companyName     16622        Description
companyName     15522        Description
```

input text file example

```
00Init    0115522   02Description                                     0116622   02Description
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a Class that represents the data fields in the file, then load / save the data into a List<Class> object u can do this also by looking up how to use the string.Split function

Comment: If the data is always guaranteed to be fixed length and that length doesn't change (70 characters per record in this instance), I would do something like: (1) read the line, (2) get the length of the line, which is hopefully a multiple of 70, (3) loop however many times 70 goes into that length, using the `.substring()` function to pull the proper section of the string, then (4) within the loop, use `substring()` again for each length of data (10, 10, 50) to pull out the individual parts.

Comment: Are the fields *exactly* the lengths you specified? (i.e. are they padded with whitespace if they do not use all available space?)

Comment: You said it is one line. However example provided in the question has three lines. Is this correct or all the three lines are supposed to be in one line?

Comment: Yes, the fields are padded with white space and are exactly the lengths I specified.

Comment: The file contains one line as it shows on the input text file example. I need to put this data in a table as it shows in the ouput example.

Comment: @Lily: just to clarify, you have a text file as input and you want a text file as output too?

Comment: @Lily Your example input file doesn't follow the rules, then.  Your "CompanyName" record is 41 characters long, for instance.

Comment: @Cory, I have the text file (input text file example) and I want to insert the "output" in a sql table not another file. I just need direction on how to loop through the one line in this file.

Comment: @Joshua, I typed it manually since I can't post the exact file. The Company name field is 10 characters but it holds 00 + company initials. I should've written company initials instead of company name.

Comment: @Lily are the headings of each field (`00`, `01`, and `02`) part of the character limit for the fields?  i.e. Can `CompanyName` only contain 8 characters, or can it contain 10?

Comment: Thank you all so much for the help and interest in helping me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution assumes that the data is fixed width, and that item number will preceed description (01 before 02).  This solution will emit a record every time a description record is encountered, and deals with multiple products for the same company.

First, define a class to hold your data:

```
public class Record
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, iterate through your string, returning a record when you've got a description:

```
public static IEnumerable<Record> ReadFile(string input)
{
    // Alter these as appropriate
    const int RECORDTYPELENGTH = 2;
    const int COMPANYNAMELENGTH = 41;
    const int ITEMNUMBERLENGTH = 8;
    const int DESCRIPTIONLENGTH = 48;

    int index = 0;
    string companyName = null;
    string itemNumber = null;

    while (index < input.Length)
    {
        string recordType = input.Substring(index, RECORDTYPELENGTH);
        index += RECORDTYPELENGTH;

        if (recordType == "00")
        {
            companyName = input.Substring(index, COMPANYNAMELENGTH).Trim();
            index += COMPANYNAMELENGTH;
        }
        else if (recordType == "01")
        {
            itemNumber = input.Substring(index, ITEMNUMBERLENGTH).Trim();
            index += ITEMNUMBERLENGTH;
        }
        else if (recordType == "02")
        {
            string description = input.Substring(index, DESCRIPTIONLENGTH).Trim();
            index += DESCRIPTIONLENGTH;

            yield return new Record
            {
                CompanyName = companyName,
                ItemNumber = itemNumber,
                Description = description
            };
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new FormatException("Unexpected record type " + recordType);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your field lengths in the question don't match the sample data, so I adjusted them so that the solution worked with the data you provided.  You can adjust the field lengths by adjusting the constants.

Use this like the following:

```
string input = "00CompanyName                              0115522   02Description                                     0116622   02Description                                     ";

foreach (var record in ReadFile(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", record.CompanyName, record.ItemNumber, record.Description);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I was looking for an idea but your example is great.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the whole file into a string, you have a couple options.

One, it might be useful to use [string.split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx).

Another option would be to use [string.indexof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx). Once you have the index, you could use string.substring

Comment: If splitting on `00`, `01`, and `02`, as indicated, the data *must not* contain that text, or it will be detected as a delimiter.

Comment: There are no delimiters, what do you plan on passing in to Split and IndexOf to split the text apart correctly?

Comment: I tried to use IndexOf, but if the item number has 01 or 02 then it will grab the wrong data.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The question says "*Record starting with 00*".  It's even shown in the example input file.

Comment: And if my company name is "00 Buckshot Inc."?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming fixed-width as specified, lets create two simple classes to hold a client and its related data as a list:

```
    // can hold as many items (data) as there are in the line
    public class Client
    {
        public string name;
        public List<ClientData> data;
    };

    // one single item in the client data
    public class ClientData
    {
        public string code;
        public string description;
    };
```

To parse a single line (which is assumed to have a single client and a successive list of item/description), we can do this (note: for simplification I'm just creating a static class with a static method in it):

```
    // this parser will read as many itens as there are in the line
    // and return a Client instance with those inside.
    public static class Parser
    {
        public static Client ParseData(string line)
        {
            Client client = new Client ();
            client.data = new List<ClientData> ();
            client.name = line.Substring (2, 10);

            // remove the client name
            line = line.Substring (12);

            while (line.Length > 0)
            {
                // create new item
                ClientData data = new ClientData ();
                data.code = line.Substring (2, 10);
                data.description = line.Substring (14, 50);
                client.data.Add (data);

                // next item
                line = line.Substring (64);
            }

            return client;
        }
    }
```

So, in your main loop, just after reading a new line from the file, you can call the above method to receive a new client. Something like this:

```
        // should be from a file but this is just an example
        string[] lines = {
            "00XXXXXXXXXX01YYYYYYYYYY02XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX",
            "00XXXXXXXXXX01YYYYYYYYYY02XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX01YYYYYYYYYY02XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX",
            "00XXXXXXXXXX01YYYYYYYYYY02XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX",
            "00XXXXXXXXXX01YYYYYYYYYY02XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX",
            "00XXXXXXXXXX01YYYYYYYYYY02XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX",
        };

        // loop through each line
        // (lines can have multiple items)
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Client client = Parser.ParseData (line);
            Console.WriteLine ("Read: " + client.name);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Contents of `Sample.txt`:

```
00Company1  0115522     02This is a description for company 1.              00Company2  0115523     02This is a description for company 2.              00Company3  0115524     02This is a description for company 3
```

Note that in the code below, the fields are 2 characters longer than those specified in the original question.  This is because I am including the headings in the length of each field, thus a field of  a length of `10`is effectively `12` by including the `00` from the heading.  If this is undesirable, tweak the offsets of the entries in the `fieldLengths` array.

```
String directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
String file = "Sample.txt";
String path = Path.Combine(directory, file);
Int32[] fieldLengths = new Int32[] { 12, 12, 52 };

List<RowData> rows = new List<RowData>();

Byte[] buffer = new Byte[fieldLengths.Sum()];
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    while (stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
    {
        List<String> fieldValues = new List<String>();

        Int32 offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldLengths.Length; i++)
        {
            var value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, fieldLengths[i]);
            fieldValues.Add(value);
            offset += fieldLengths[i];
        }

        String companyName = fieldValues[0];
        String itemNumber = fieldValues[1];
        String description = fieldValues[2];

        var row = new RowData(companyName, itemNumber, description);
        rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Class definition for `RowData`:

```
public class RowData
{
    public String Company { get; set; }
    public String Number { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public RowData(String company, String number, String description)
    {
        Company = company;
        Number = number;
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

The results will be in the `rows` variable.

Comment: In the OP's sample data, there is a single company record followed by multiple product/description pairs.  Your answer is not looking at the record types, but looking for sequences of 00, 01, 02, 00, 01, 02...

Comment: thank you Joshua so much for helping out.

Comment: @Richard The wording in the OP differs from the example listed.  It's wording implies that each record has a `00`, `01` and `02` heading.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to split rows based on a delimiter. It would seem that in your case you are using whitespace as a delimiter.

The method you are looking for is String.Split(), it should cover your needs :) Documentation is located at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx - It also includes examples.

I'd do something like this:

```
string myLineOfText = "MyCompany    12345    The description of my company";
string[] partsOfMyLine = myLineOfText.Split(new string[] { "    " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Best of luck! :)

Comment: I downvoted because this solution won't work all the time. What if the values took up their entire alotted length, so there weren't any spaces separating the data points? Split() would return an array with 1 item in it (the original string) in that case.

Comment: @Cory Well, I wrote it under the assumption that OP used a tab delimited file as indicated by his post. I suppose I shouldn't have assumed.